# Google like SearchBox in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, autocomplete, drop-down-menu

I've created a Google like SearchBox control in Silverlight. That means, as I type in the box, a DropDownListBox appears just below the SearchBox, showing all the items that match with the text I've typed in searchbox so far (i.e AutoComplete feature), exactly like this:

[image: Google like SearchBox in Silverlight]

Now, I want to add a functionality to it : I want to make the DropDownListBox to disappear, as soon as user clicks outside it, or anywhere on the screen. I cannot handle `MouseLeftButtonDown` (or any such `event`) in other controls, to accomplish this, because users can click anywhere, including non-silverlight region. Can anybody suggest me what should I do to achieve this?

So my question basically is:

**How to know if user has just clicked and the click event occurred outside a particular control?**

Please note that `AutoCompleteBox` doesn't serve my purpose. So I cannot use it.

Comment: what about Silverlight Toolkit's Autocomplete TextBox?

Comment: @Shoaib: It seems you didn't read my post to the end. :-)

Comment: sorry i didnt noticed. i think lostFocus can help as Raf pointed it.

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling that working with [**LostFocus**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this question is a bit old, but i just stumble upon trying to do the same and finding a solution. This is what i did

- Created a Border with All Margins -500, this will cover the full screen essentially.
- On Click Behaviour of this Border, the dropdown section of SearchBox
  is collapsed.
- Adjust z-Index of Border just below the SearchBox and DropDown
  section, so clicking on SearchBox or DropDown wouldn't close it.
- Set Border Visibility Collapsed, and make it visible when DropDown is Visible.

I hope it helps someone who is looking for the similar problem.