# How to detect mouse clicks without listening to any mouse events defined in framework controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

Is it possible to detect mouse clicks without listening to any mouse events defined in framework controls?

I mean, I don't want to write code like :

```
  control.MouseLeftButtonDown += this.HandleMouseLeftButtonDown;
```

Yet I want to know if user clicks on the screen or not. Is it possible in C# (WPF or Silverlight)?

Comment: It's difficult to even contemplate an answer to this question without a better understanding of what exactly you're trying to do and *why* you feel the need to avoid handling the standard mouse events. Are you just trying to do things the hard way, or is there a specific design consideration at work here?

Comment: @Code Gray: I want to do this : [Google like SearchBox in Silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861221/google-like-searchbox-in-silverlight)

Comment: @Nawaz: "So my question basically is: How to know if user has just clicked and the click event occurred outside a particular control?" How is this not an exact duplicate?

Comment: @Cody Gray:  That topic is about some particular context. This topic is more general!

Comment: As hinted earlier, I feel like the context is what makes it a real question. Beyond that, I don't understand how the answers would be expected to differ.

Comment: @Cody Gray: In that topic my aim is to add particular functionality to my existing SearchBox; the question I've asked there is "my" thought; "I" think if I get answer to that question, I would be able to solve the problem. But knowing the context participants there may suggest me alternative solution, without answering my question. That would still be helpful to me. Are you getting what I'm saying? But here, I posed a more general question.

Answer (score 8):

You can register a class handler in a static constructor you your main window, for example:

```
static MainWindow() {
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof (MainWindow),
                                      Mouse.MouseDownEvent,
                                      new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnGlobaMouseDown));
}
```

It will be a global handler for all MouseDown events.

Comment: Nice but a downside might be that the handler needs to be a static method. Also i'd probably add the bool for `handledEventToo` in the register method because otherwise very few events reach the specified handler.

Comment: What if user clicks outside MainWindow? He could click on the browser url box, or OS task bar, Windows 7 `Start` button, etc?

Comment: @Nawaz - If you need to detect mouse events outside your WPF application, I think you will have to use Win API. See answer of James Gaunt.

Comment: How do you do this for Silverlight in-browser app?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the Win32 API and detect the mouse message WM_MOUSE, something like this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804

or this example, showing use of the global mouse message WM_MOUSE_LL:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

Answer (score 4):

This is done by capturing the mouse.  Which forces any mouse event to be directed to you, even if it moves outside of the window.  Mouse.Capture() method.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle mouse events of all your application, the best way is to subscribe to [InputManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputmanager_events.aspx) events.

Answer (score 0):

> "I mean, I don't want to write code like :
>
> control.MouseLeftButtonDown += this.HandleMouseLeftButtonDown;"

You could always use:

```
if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
{
     ...
}
```

You will need to include this though.

```
using System.Windows.Input;
```

This works for me in wpf.